# How to access the changing key in an associative multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
array: [
  0 => array: [
    "key 1" => "user 1",
    "count" => "14"
  ],
  1 => array: [
    "key 2" => "user 2",
    "count" => "7"
  ],
  2 => array: [
    "key 2" => "user 1",
    "count" => "1"
  ]
]
```

I have to count the count values ​​for each key. But the names of keys have different names. And I do not know how to get access to them.
I want to get such result:

```
array: [
  0 => array: [
    "user" => "user 1",
    "key 1" => "14",
    "key 2" => "1",
  ],
  1 => array: [
    "user" => "user 2",
    "key 2" => "7"
  ]
```

I tried to use two foreach loops

```
foreach ($result as $k=>$v)
            {
                foreach ($v as $k2=>$v2) {
                    $final[]["user"] = $result[$k][$k2];
                }
            }
```

But the result is incorrect

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1011527)

Comment: "I tried to use two foreach"  So show that attempt.

Comment: Does the user keys is always the first? Does user name always starts with `"user "`?

Comment: @Syscall , Yes keys are always first.As on the presented array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
$result = [
  ["key 1" => "user 1", "count" => "14"],
  ["key 2" => "user 2", "count" => "7"],
  ["key 2" => "user 1", "count" => "1"]
];


$out = [] ; // output array 
foreach ($result as $val) {
    $keys = array_keys($val); // get the keys "key 1", "count" as array
    $uid = reset($val); // get the first value "user 1"
    $out[$uid]['user'] = reset($val); // store the user name
    $out[$uid][reset($keys)] = $val['count']; // store the count into "key N" key. 
}
$out = array_values($out); // reindex keys 
print_r($out); // output data (optional)
```

Outputs :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user] => user 1
            [key 1] => 14
            [key 2] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user] => user 2
            [key 2] => 7
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed `user x` and `key x` were just placeholders for any values.

```
$b = array();
foreach ($a as $row)
{
    $values = array_values($row);
    $keys = array_keys($row);

    //Extract data from keys / values
    $user = $values[0];
    $key = $keys[0];
    $count = $values[1];

    //Create element in output array and insert user info
    if ( ! isset($b[$user]))
    {
        $b[$user] = array('user' => $user);
    }

    //Add key info
    $b[$user][$key] = $count;
}
//Rewrite array keys to 0, 1, 2, ...
$b = array_values($b);
```

**edit:** comments added